# workflow_run not triggered as expected after parent workflow completes

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow that I would like to execute either via `workflow_dispatch` or `workflow_run`.

The first is only executed manually at the moment:

```
name: upload

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
```

The second should be able to be executed either manually, or on completion of `upload`

```
name: archive

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["upload"]
    types:
      - completed
```

The `archive` workflow is executed as expected when initiated manually but it is not starting after `upload` completes.  The cause is not clear to me.  Any pointers?

Please note that I have read the following:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run

Comment: Are both workflow files on the default branch?

Comment: @SpenserBlack yes they are.  both can be executed via dispatch.

Answer (score 5):

Annoyingly, this was due to using apostrophes in the workflow name in `workflows: ["upload"]`:

**not working:**

```
name: archive

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["upload"]   <- issue here
    types:
      - completed
```

**working:**

```
name: archive

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [upload]
    types:
      - completed
```

Comment: What if I have spaces in the name of the workflow, something like 
`name: terraform automation` ?